Proof of the existence of algebraic closure
I am taking an introductory course on Galois theory, and we recently covered the following theorem:
For every field $\mathbb{F}$, there exists a field extension $\mathbb{L}$ which is algebraically closed.
In class, the proof involved constructing a tower of extensions $\mathbb{F} = L_0 \subset L_1 \subset \cdots$, where each polynomial in $L_i$ has a root in $L_{i+1}$.
As an exercise, we were asked to prove that $L = \bigcup L_i$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}$.
I understand why every polynomial has a root in some extension, but I am having trouble understanding why each element of $L$ must be the root of a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}$.
Could someone explain how to approach this proof and clarify why $L$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb{F}$?
Thank you!

We need a little information on how the $L_n$ are constructed. This is certainly not true for any such sequence of extensions. Consider $\mathbb{F}={0,1}\subset\mathbb{C}\subset\mathbb{C}\subset...$
